# pandas - move multiple columns with the same name and different missing data into single column then delete duplicate columns

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, missing-data, melt

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Col1  | Col2  | Col1  | Col3  | Col1  | Col4
  a   |   d   |       |   h   |   a   |   p
  b   |   e   |   b   |   i   |   b   |   l
      |   l   |   a   |   l   |       |   a
  l   |   r   |   l   |   a   |   l   |   x
  a   |   i   |   a   |   w   |       |   i
      |   c   |       |   i   |   r   |   c
  d   |   o   |   d   |   e   |   d   |   o
```

`Col1` is repeated multiple times in the dataframe. In each `Col1`, there is missing information. I need to create a new column that has all of the information from each `Col1` occurrence.

**How can I create a column with the complete information and then delete the previous duplicate columns?**

Some information may be missing from multiple columns. This script is also meant to be used in the future when there could be one, three, five, or any number of duplicated `Col1` columns.

The desired output looks like this:

```
Col2  | Col3  | Col4  | Col5
  d   |   h   |   p   |   a
  e   |   i   |   l   |   b
  l   |   l   |   a   |   a
  r   |   a   |   x   |   l
  i   |   w   |   i   |   a
  c   |   i   |   c   |   r
  o   |   e   |   o   |   d
```

I have been looking over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613396/how-to-select-and-delete-columns-with-duplicate-name-in-pandas-dataframe)  but it is not clear to me how I could keep the desired `Col1` with complete values. I could delete multiple columns of the same name but I need to first create a column with complete information.

Comment: They all have the same name?

Comment: You need to give more info. How do you come up with values of `Col1` and `Col5` of the desired output? why is `Col1` of the output  the same as `Col4` of the sample data?

Comment: Are you **certain** that when the column is duplicated the values in each row are always the same when not missing? It's `groupby` + `first` in that case.

Comment: I can't get a dataframe to have the same name columns, it renames the to Col1.1 and Col1.2 , etc

Comment: @oppressionslayer that because pandas really doesn't want them to be duplicated and in general it's not great when they are (though in this case it seems useful). You can get around that by manually providing a list to set columns: `df.columns = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col1', 'Col3', 'Col1', 'Col4']`

Comment: Your expected output is wrong. Col1 does not contain `p` or `x` or `i` in the input but you show in the output

Comment: @ALollz that worked, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First replace empty values in your columns with `nan` as below:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

Then, you could use `groupby` and then `first()`

```
df.groupby(level = 0, axis = 1).first()
```

Comment: This seemed to work but I want to note it shifted reordered the columns. I am accepting this answer because in the original question I did not specify that column order must remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this is what you are looking for.

```
col_list = list(set(df.columns))
dicts={}
for col in col_list:
    val = list(filter(None,set(df.filter(like=col).stack().reset_index()[0].str.strip(' ').tolist())))
    dicts[col]= val
max_len=max([len(k) for k in dicts.values()])
pd.DataFrame({k:pd.Series(v[:max_len]) for k,v in dicts.items()})
```

**output**

```
   Col3     Col4    Col1    Col2
0   h          i    d       d
1   w          l    b       r
2   i          c    r       i
3   l          x    l       l
4   a          p    a       o
5   e          o    NaN     c
6   NaN        a    NaN     e
```